# Best way to convert HTMLto CSHTML

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a few dozen HTML forms that I need to convert to ASP.NET MVC Razor partial views (CSHTML).  Specifically, I need to convert each  to a @Html.TextBox.  For example, convert

```
<input name="text1" style="margin:0pt"></input>
```

to

```
@Html.TextBox("text1", String.Empty, new { style = "margin:0pt" })
```

and then save the file to a new CSHTML file.  Of course, the input tag could be coded as

```
<input .../> or as <input ...></input>
```

and the tag may or may not have a style attribute.

Anyone know of an automated way that I could do this?  The alternative is to manually make the changes, which would be rather time-consuming.  I was thinking some regular expression magic would be the way to go, or perhaps using some kind of HTML DOM parser, but I'm not much of a Regex god and I'm not familiar with any parsing components that would help.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that the form elements needs to be converted at all?

Comment: What @Guffa said, do you have a particular need to convert them? You can use them as-is.

Comment: Yes, they need to be converted because I'll be doing some server-side auto-populating of the values.

Comment: You can populate the values without converting them.  All the helpers do is simplify the creation of the fields.  If you already have them, then the work is already done.  All those helpers do is create a shortcut that does what you could do by hand.  Now, it would be different if you were planning to use ModelFor or something, but if you're just populating some input fields, just use what you already have.

Comment: So you have a problem and you want to solve it using regular expressions? Now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
    private static void ReplaceInputTagsWithHtmlTextBox(string filePath)
    {
        var input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        var keyValueRegex = new Regex("\\s*(?<key>[^=]*)=\\s*['\"](?<value>[^'\"]*)['\"]");
        var values = new List<string>();
        var regex = new Regex(@"<input (?<Attributes>[^>]*)>(</input>)?");
        var newContent = regex.Replace(input, m =>
        {
            var keyValueDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var allAttributes = m.Groups["Attributes"].Value;
            keyValueRegex.Replace(m.Groups["Attributes"].Value, mm =>
            {
                keyValueDict.Add(mm.Groups["key"].Value, mm.Groups["value"].Value);
                return null;
            });
            var keyValues = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in keyValueDict)
            {
                if (!pair.Key.Equals("id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !pair.Key.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && !pair.Key.Equals("value", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))//don't include id, name and value
                    keyValues.Append(pair.Key.Replace("class", "@class") + "= \"" + pair.Value + "\", ");
            }
            var keyValuesString = keyValues.ToString();
            if (keyValuesString.EndsWith(", "))
                keyValuesString = keyValuesString.Remove(keyValuesString.Length - 2, 2);
            if (!keyValueDict.ContainsKey("name") || keyValueDict["name"] == null)
                keyValueDict["name"] = "";
            if (!keyValueDict.ContainsKey("value") || keyValueDict["value"] == null)
                keyValueDict["value"] = "";
            return String.Format("@Html.TextBox(\"{0}\", \"{1}\", new {{ {2} }})\n", keyValueDict["name"], keyValueDict["value"], keyValuesString);
        });
        using (StreamWriter outfile =new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            outfile.Write(newContent);
        }
    }
```

Now jus call it using,

```
ReplaceInputTagsWithHtmlTextBox("Temp.cshtml");
```